# Rails associations when unique and common models combine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model-associations

First of all, I want to apologize for my terminology. I am not entirely sure what to call what I am looking for, so I can’t google for answers. But here is my problem.

I am working on a Rails application that stores information about different websites and provides various services for them. I will call these services ‘Products.’ One website can be subscribed to several products, and a product can be served to various websites. So here is a very simple association scheme for these relationships:

[image]

At least, it would have been simple, but the problem is that the Settings model (shown in red on this diagram) is different for each product: for one product, it will have one number of fields and data types, for another it will have a different number of fields with different data types. On the other hand, the Faq and Description are the same, so if I redraw the diagram as follows:

[image]

I will get another problem: too much repetition (shown in blue on the diagram). Ideally, I want some kind of modification of the first diagram, where the Product model will choose differens Settings models depending on a parameter that I pass to it:

[image]

So that a request website.products.find(1).settings will return the model Settings1, while a request website.products.find(2).settings will return a completely different model, Settings2.

Is this achievable in Rails? If not, how would you organize such data?

Comment: have you check polymorphic relation ships in rails. i am sure it will help you

Comment: Hmm, yes, I think you are right, I could probably use polymorphic associations to avoid repetition in my second diagram.